Sometimes my code runs and sometimes it does not
I work for a big organisation and we have some large Google Sheets that multiple users use (however maybe at one time it would be maximum 7-10). I am working on automating some processes for this sheet. For example one of the Apps Scripts I am working on, I would like users to once they have inputted data into a row to complete a QA check and once completed they would input 'r' into one of the cells and this will then print out the users email and date they reviewed.
The issue is, this does work. however sometimes it wont work for some cells and some sheets. some days it wont work at all and some days it does. I checked the google app script quota limits and from what it seems we are not exceeding the limit here. Therefore I am completely baffled as to why its not working, perhaps its my code?
Maybe there's a way to optimise this code, too? It's annoying to have to keep updating the column index numbers if changes happen to the sheet. The column title is the same on all the sheets (QA), so I thought about using that as a reference instead of referring to each sheet and the index of the column affected.
function team_QA(e) {
  // Ensure the event object is defined, if false ignore
  if (!e) return;

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // Define the columns to watch for each sheet
  var sheetConfigurations = {
    'Paid': 123, // Column DS
    'Dis': 137,   // Column EH
    'Review': 115, // Column DK
    'Third': 115, // Column DK
    'Lead: 119 // Column DO
  };

  // Check if the edited sheet is one of the specified sheets
  if (!sheetConfigurations.hasOwnProperty(sheetName)) {
    return;
  }

  // Get the column to watch for the current sheet
  var columnToWatch = sheetConfigurations[sheetName];

  // Get the range of the cell that was edited
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();

  // Check if the edited cell is in the column to watch and contains "R"
  if (column == columnToWatch && range.getValue() == "r") {
    // Get the user's email and current date
    var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var currentDate = new Date();

    // Format the date as desired
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(currentDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yy");

    // Combine the email and date
    var reviewInfo = userEmail + " reviewed on " + formattedDate;
    
    // Set the review information in the edited cell
    range.setValue(reviewInfo);
  }
}


It's been known for a long time 1 that edit triggers might not be activated for all edit events. The official documentation was updated to reflect this in the section about the edit simple trigger:
From Simple Triggers

Note: The onEdit() trigger only queues up to 2 trigger events.

This behavior can be noticed in simple sheets with an onEdit simple trigger by quickly editing several cells, i.e.,

Preparation: Create a new spreadsheet and add the following simple trigger. It adds a timestamp to the first cell to the right of the top left cell of the edited range.
function onEdit(e){
  e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
}


Edit A1 by pressing R, then press Enter.
This will queue an edit event and make A2 the current cell.

Immediately Edit A2 by pressing R, then press Enter.
This will queue an edit event and make A3 the current cell.

Continue editing the new current cell, let's say ten times. Please ensure to do it as fast as possible.

Wait a bit to let the queued edit events activate the onEdit simple trigger.

Look at column B. Not all the cells in column B will have a timestamp.
Look at the executions page. There, you will notice that the number of executions of the onEdit trigger is less than the number of edited cells.



Installable triggers might also miss events due to queue limitations as they work "on best effort basis" (quote source pending).
Suggestion
Whenever possible, design your spreadsheet to avoid users being able to make many edits quickly.  When this is impossible, take measures to handle the missed trigger activation, including the corresponding training for the spreadsheet users about these measures.
Ideas

For edits that could be done quickly, i.e., by entering a single letter on multiple contiguous cells or clicking multiple checkboxes, instead of relying on an edit trigger, use a custom menu to activate a function to update the dependent cells. Alternatively, consider using an alternate data entry method, such as another spreadsheet or an HTML form presented using a dialog or sidebar (HTML Service) and a button to send all the changes simultaneously, including updating the dependent cells.

Create an app using AppSheet.

Create a web app using Google Apps Script (HTML Service)

Use another service for fast data entry, then use Google Sheets API or a no-code/low-code service like IFTTT or Zapier, among others, to integrate the other service with your spreadsheets.


Related Feature request
Feature requests should be asked on the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker. Below is a related feature request, if you would like to support it, please "star" it.

Only two onEdit trigger events can be queued at a time in New Sheets

Related

Failure of calling Google App Script onEdit function many times in a second
onEdit() doesn't catch all changes

Footnotes

This was reported on the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker then years ago:

Only two onEdit trigger events can be queued at a time in New Sheets



